# What are the implications of converting Documents in a library to a new Content Type?

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub

If I have an existing set of documents in a document library, and I created a new Content Type with required fields, what are the implications when I apply that content type to the library?

We are constructing a Knowledge Base and have a Knowledge Document Content Type that has a column that categorizes content as belonging to a specific business process and is required.  When I apply the content type to an existing library, this column will be blank... but it is required.  Is this an issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the new content type (Type B) to the library alongside the default content type (Type A), it will not impact the documents currently in the library, they will retain content type A.

The existing documents will be impacted if you change them to content type B as they will have the metadata for content type B and any data for columns in content type A will still be preserved.

The required field will come into play if you edit an existing document by changing it to content type B and then edit its properties, at that time the required field rule will be enforced.